# How to undo JQuery selector html() redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, .net, razor

How do I undit the redirect HTML setup to my partial after I am done with it?

I'm using an ajax call to retrieve data for a partial view. JQuery html() helps in redirecting the responce to the partial. However, in this solution there is a a refresh that is happening that triggers OnGet and refreshes the whole page. In this case, the whole page refresh is now directed to the partial view index of the index.cshtml page.

```
$.post('/reports/AddReportData',
        formData
    )
    .done(function (response) {
            $("#myPartialView").html(response);
    });
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown will cause any 'refreshes'. If you're seeing that behaviour, then it's possible other logic is being directly invoked by your logic, or by an event handler bound to an element. From the context, I'd assume you're submitting a `form` to fire the AJAX request, but you've forgotten to call `preventDefault()` on that form submission.

Comment: I do have a preventDefault but you are correct, there is some other routing issue causing a second call to OnPost().

Answer (score -1):

In my case there was a routing issue that caused a second post to OnPost(). Resolving the routing issue is the fix.